# Stopping filter(), is it possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have this kind of code:

```
        return Object.keys(items).filter((item, index) => {
        if(index <= this.state.limit)
            return item

        if(index > this.state.limit)
            break? continue to the maping? how?
    }).map( (item, index) => {
        return(
            <div key={index}>
                {item.title}
            </div>
        )
    })
```

how can I exit from filter after and go to the maping instead of looping through all of the items. Is it possible? I tried break and continue but did not worked.

The array (items) within the object keys is an object with a bunch of props, around 5000 thousands)

```
const items = {
    title2: 'bird',
    title3: 'apple,
    title4 ....
}
```

I need basically return the amount the **first N** amount of props in object, depending on the **this.state.limit**

Comment: Can we see your array? Because you could simply use slice, you seem to use filter to just get the first X elements...

Comment: @Salketer edited my post

Comment: Thanks. I think you got a problem with that object in the first place... You'd be better having an array of objects instead, or else you cannot be certain of what elements will be shown as keys order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Just return `false` for items you don't want:

```
return Object.keys(items)
    .filter((item, index) => index <= this.state.limit)
    .map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            {item.title}
        </div>
    ));
```

You can't stop a `filter` to stop looping, but the code above will work flawlessly.

---

If you want to iterate only the first `N` elements efficiently, you can use a `for` loop:

```
// get your array you want to iterate
const list = Object.keys(items);

// nodes will contain results from (0) to (this.state.limit)
const nodes = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.limit; i++) {
    nodes.push((
        <div key={i}>
            {list[i].title}
        </div>
    ));
}

return nodes;
```

---

**Note:** if your data is like this:

```
const items = {
    title2: 'bird',
    title3: 'apple',
    // and so on
}
```

And you want to print `bird`, `apple`, etc..., you may want to use `Object.values` instead of `keys`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead of `filter` to limit array length

```
return Object.values(items)
             .slice(0, this.state.limit + 1)
             .map( (item, index) => {
               return (
                 <div key={index}>
                  {item.title}
                 </div>
               )
             })
```

But you should keep in mind that the order of properties in object is **NOT** guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot break in between a filter, you would have to throw an exception and later catch it if you want to stop it. instead try this

```
if(index > this.state.limit)
    return 1; // return 1 if you want to keep those objects or 0 if you don't
```

Comment: or simply `return index <= this.state.limit`